# Using selectInput choices as x and y plot variables

Tags: r, excel, shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

 titlePanel("To-Fest"),
 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose File', accept = ".xlsx"),

  #downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'),
  tags$hr(),
  checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
  tags$hr(),
  selectInput("select1", "Select X Variable", choices =c()),
  tags$hr(),
  selectInput("select2", "Select Y Variable", choices =c()),

  uiOutput("choose_columns")

  ),
    mainPanel(

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Data", tableOutput('contents')),
     tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput('plot1'))

    )
  )
  )
))
  library(shiny)
 library(xlsx)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  dsnames <- c()

 rawData <- reactive({
   filet <- input$file1
   if(is.null(filet)) return()
   rawData <- read.xlsx2(filet$datapath, sheetIndex = 1)
 })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
   rawData()
  })

 observe({
  dsnames <- names(rawData())
  cb_options <- list()
   cb_options[ dsnames] <- dsnames
  updateSelectInput(session, "select1",
                         label = "Select x-axis",
                         choices = cb_options,
                         selected = "")
  updateSelectInput(session, "select2",
                  label = "Select y-axis",
                  choices = cb_options,
                  selected = "")
 })

output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
  selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(dsnames))
})

 output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

  if(is.null(input$dataset))
  return()

  colnames <- names(contents)

  selectInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                   choices  = colnames,
                   selected = NULL)
})

x <- reactive({
  xval <- rawData(input$select1)
  xval
})

 y <- reactive({
  yval <- rawData(input$select2)
yval
 })

 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  plot(x,y)
})

})
```

These are my ui and server files and I'm trying to make an app where you can upload an Excel file and use the column headers as the choices that are listed in both selectInput widgets. I have gotten this part to work, but then I would like to plot both selections against each other as X and Y variables. I tried making reactive functions for x and y but I have been unsuccessful in getting this to work. I also keep getting the error:

```
 cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'.
```

Comment: Use reactive values as `x()` `y()`. The parenthesis is needed.

Comment: Thanks man, I completely forgot the parentheses haha.  I made some minor changes and got it working